# Lennox G40UH furnace not turning on

Tags: hvac, heating, lennox

With the lower panel door switch closed, the combustion air inducer comes on.  It runs for a little while and then shuts down.  Nothing happens in the meantime.  The system was working fine until this morning and now it is not.  Any help will be most appreciated.

The blower motor or the gas never turns on.  I do not see the igniter turning hot either.

Comment: Never mind guys.  I cleaned the contacts of the air pressure proving switch and cleaned its hole with a wire.  Refitted.  Furnace working fine now.  Hopefully this may help someone else with a similar problem.

Comment: Post that as an answer and I'll give it a +1 :)